# Custom directives is not working in Angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

While running the following code it should be focused(like cursor on button) on the button named focussed shown here. But its not working

[image]

Html code :

```
<body ng-controller="TextController">
 <button ng-click="clickUnfocused()">Not focussed</button>
 <button ngbk-focus ng-click="clickfocused()">focussed</button>
 <div>{{message.text}}</div>
</body>
```

Javascript code :

```
var kitkatmodule = angular.module('Kitkat', ['directives']);

    kitkatmodule.controller('TextController',function($scope) {

         $scope.message = {text:"nothin clicked"};

         $scope.clickUnfocused = function() {
         $scope.message.text = "Click Unfocused";
         }
         $scope.clickfocused = function() {
         $scope.message.text = "clickfocused";
         }
    });

    kitkatmodule.directive('ngbkFocus', function(){
        return  {
            link : function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                element[0].focus();
            }
        };
    });
```

How to fix this

Comment: Can you show your markup for `ng-app`.  The error says `Kitkatty` where your module name is acutally `Kitkat`.

Comment: @Davin I have edited my code you can try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while working with directives we need to add angular-resource.js file

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject 'directives' into your module unless you intend to inject a new module for the directive later.  Your controller should also be declared in a way similar to this example:

```
function TextController($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}
```

Comment: See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a7EhG/.  Just make sure that you are using ng-app="kitkat" where you declare it.

Comment: `kitkatmodule.controller('TextController',function($scope) {` is IMHO a better way to define a controller.  Yours is a global function.

Comment: @C1pher i have edited my code from your fiddle. Now the problem is the button hover directive(ngbk-focus) is not working .Am i missing anything?

Comment: @DavinTryon You're right.  I haven't seen that style of declaration before, but I understand that the global scope can be dangerous.  Thank you.

Comment: @Cashew What do you want to do after setting the focus on the button?

Comment: @C1pher the button[focused] should be autofucused when the page is loaded

Comment: @Cashew I'm not sure.  'element[0].focus();' should work.  A watch would work if you were looking for a trigger, but the directive should already be loading on page load.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42050/discussion-between-cashew-and-c1pher)

Answer (score 0):

Just removing the '`directives`' you have included while declaring the module makes the code work. Also take care you have declared ng-App. I haven't included `angular-resources.js` but still it works for me. Have just included the `angular.min.js`.